# "No such file or directory" when opening terminal

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminal

I'm trying to launch ec2 but I am getting these messages when I open up terminal. Some context: I was previously getting a memory error when running a script through ec2, and so I changed my instance type from t2.small to t3.2xlarge to see if adding more memory might help run it. Now I can't even run the script because I cant launch ec2 and now getting these messages. I suspect that changing the instance type might have caused this, but not entirely positive. I having a hard time understanding this as I am fairly new to using ec2, so any help/direction would be much appreciated!

```
-bash: /Users/user1/Downloads/ep_key.pem: Permission denied
-bash: /Users/user1/Warner: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/user1/.bash_profile: line 145: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /Users/user1/.bash_profile: line 154: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Do you launch your ec2 instance from bash or powershell or from the AWS console ? Did you check the [prerequisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-instances.html) ?

Comment: from bash. I was launching ec2 successfully up until I changed the instance type.

Comment: Did you run the ec2 command from a different userid than the one used to create the instance ?

Comment: No it was from the same userid. Nothing changed other than the instance type. I'm just assuming that changing the type is what's causing the issue because I didnt change anything else

Comment: Could you give us the output of `ls -ld /Users/user1/Downloads/ep_key.pem` ?

Comment: Your description is confusing. You say that you can't launch the EC2 instance, but you also claim to be getting messages when connecting to it? If the above errors are appearing when you _try_ to connect to the EC2 instance, then those messages are coming from _your own computer_, before even connecting to the EC2 instance. Please edit your question to include the command that you used that resulted in these messages. The messages suggest to me that your command referenced the `ep_key.pem` file, but it either does not exist on your computer or you do not have permission to access it.

Comment: @Zilog80 This is the output: ls: /Users/user1/Downloads/ep_key.pem: No such file or directory

Comment: You have to setup  a new key pairs as decribed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-keypairs.html)

Comment: So after changing the instance type, I need to set up new key pairs? I'll give that a shot. @Zilog80

Comment: @JohnRotenstein So the messages actually appear when I open terminal, before even trying to launch EC2. When I do attempt to launch EC2, I get this message: "ssh: connect to host ec2-54-198-175-51.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out"

Comment: You do not need to change the key pairs, use your previous key pair, because you were already using this key before.

Comment: Please note that the instance is given a **different public IP address** when it is stopped and started (unless you assign a static Elastic IP address). Therefore, make sure that you are connecting to the correct instance. Also, you should specify the username as part of the SSH command, eg `ssh -i file.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4` Any messages that appear when you start the terminal (before you type a command) are either old messages, or would be caused by a bad configuration in your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

AWS allows for you to change your instance type, when you have created your instance. When you stop your instance, and you not using an elastic ip address, the public DNS name and the public ip address of the instance changes each time.

Comment: I successfully changed the instance type and then started running the instance again.

Comment: Review the permissions on the ep_key.pem, on your local machine, and then try connecting to your aws instance with the key.